# What's a reliable way to sanitize a die string, removing the " at File.pm line 123"?

Tags: regex, perl, exception, die

Sometimes I'd like to handle a Perl string exception that comes with the " at File.pm line 123" on the end of it by outputting it somewhere. However, I don't really want to expose that last bit with the path name, the line number, etc.

Over time I've come up with several possible solutions and I've liked none of them very well. Just using a regular expression like this is one obvious one:

```perl
s/\s+ at \s+ .*$//xms;
```

but has the problem that it will kill just about anything with the word " at " in it. Making the line number non-optional helps, but then you end up with anonymous code having " at ANON" or something similarly grotesque staying on.

I have even tried something like this:

```perl
$_ = reverse $_;
s/^.*? \s+ ta \s+//xms;
$_ = reverse $_;
```

which works pretty well on one-line errors. But if you end up with a full stack trace from `confess` or some other exception thrower, you end up with the long stack trace in place.

Anyone have a good solution they'd care to share? Or a suggestion on a better way? ("Don't output the die message like that" is not an acceptable answer.)

If there's a CPAN module I've overlooked to help here, I'd love to know. If not, I'm thinking of contributing a CPAN module for this purpose.

Comment: Do you know what you can prevent Perl from generating the string in the first place by appending a newline? e.g. `die "Foo: $!\n";`

Comment: Yes, but that doesn't help when it's something generated by some other code my app deals with.

Comment: I usually throw exception objects based on [Throwable](https://metacpan.org/module/Throwable) or something similar in my own app code.

Comment: Is there a case where the line number isn't given? I don't think I've ever seen that. If the last file handle you read from is still open, there can be extra. (`echo foo | perl -e'<STDIN>; die;'`)

Comment: I'm almost certain there are, but I can't find an example of it right now.

Comment: Well, if there is isn't, like I think, your problem is moot.

Comment: `\S+` won't match `(eval 1)` produced by `perl -e'(eval "sub { die }")->()'`

Comment: Aren't your two snippets (forward and reverse) 100% equivalent?

Comment: Apparently, I should have posted my question without example code. I've simplified the examples to include something even dumber that does the job. I'm still trying to find examples without lines. Digging through all my old errors to find the one that led to that.

Answer (score 4):

1. Your first snippet doesn't «kill just about anything with the word " at " in it.». `at` has to be the second last word for it do anything.
2. I think your two snippets (forward and reverse) are 100% equivalent (except that the second doesn't support a trailing newline, so it's probably never going to match).
3. The pattern

   ```
   /\s+ at \s+ \S+ (?:\s+ line \s+ \d+)?$/x
   ```

   isn't going to match

   ```
   $ perl -e'(eval "sub { die }")->()'
   Died at (eval 1) line 1.
   ```
4. The pattern

   ```
   /\s+ at \s+ \S+ (?:\s+ line \s+ \d+)?$/x
   ```

   isn't going to match

   ```
   $ echo foo | perl -e'<STDIN>; die;'
   Died at -e line 1, <STDIN> line 1.
   ```
5. I don't think Perl will ever add a file name without adding a number.

   If the line number is optional, then it's inevitable that you'll match the last two words of "Dinner is at nine." unless you start employing heuristics.

---

Looking at the source code, this is what `die` can append:

```
Adds:                   " at %s line %"IVdf
Sometimes followed by:  ", <%"SVf"> line %"IVdf
                or by:  ", <%"SVf"> chunk %"IVdf
Sometimes followed by:  " during global destruction"
Always followed by:     ".\n"
```

That gives us:

```
s/
   (?&BASE)
   (?&IO_CLAUSE)?
   (?&GLOBAL_DESTR)?
   \.?\n\z

   (?(DEFINE)
      (?<BASE>         [ ] at [ ] (?&FILE_NAME) [ ] line [ ] [0-9]+ )
      (?<IO_CLAUSE>    , [ ] <(?&HANDLE_NAME)> [ ] (?:line|chunk) [ ] [0-9]+ )
      (?<GLOBAL_DESTR> [ ]during[ ]global[ ]destruction )

      # Heuristics:
      (?<FILE_NAME>   \S+ | \(eval[ ][0-9]+\) )
      (?<HANDLE_NAME> \w+ )
   )
//x
```

That's as specific as it can be.

(Note: Carp sometimes forgets the trailing "`.`", from what I hear.)

(Note: Perl uses single spaces, so `[ ]` is more precise than `\s+`.)

Comment: My samples have been updated to be as dumb as I really meant them to be. I wasn't looking for the examples to distract from getting some answers.

Comment: Summary: My answer is: "it's moot" or "you're just going to have to live with it if you have messages that look like Perl messages" depending on whether you find such an example.

Comment: Looked at source code. `warn` and `die` always adds line number if it adds file name. Update answer.

Comment: It's been awhile, but I did find another case. I just saw this line in a stack trace: "Moose::Object::new('TestBot', 'event_loop', 'Bot::Backbone::TestEventLoop') called at generated method (unknown origin) line 3".

Comment: I didn't limit the question to just exceptions thrown by die.

Comment: You limited it to exceptions, and `die` is the only way to throw an exxception.

Comment: It's my question. I didn't limit it to die.

Comment: You asked to remove what gets added to exception messages by `die`. What does it mean to "not limit it to die"?

Comment: I asked how to handle a string exception. I wasn't and am still not concerned with how it originated. If you read more than that in to it, that wasn't what I intended to communicate.

Comment: Yes, and like I said, `die` is the only way to throw an exception, and the string you asked to remove is added by `die`. Now, it's possible to tell `die` not to add this string you've asked to remove, making the exception message completely arbitrary, but you haven't mentioned anything about other strings you want to parse before this comment you posted last week. If you want to parse some other (as-of-yet unspecified) strings, you'll have to start by identifying what those strings are.

Answer (score 2):

You could override your builtin `die` by defining a `CORE::GLOBAL::die` function:

```
BEGIN {
    *CORE::GLOBAL::die = sub {
        my $y = pop @_;
        chomp $y;
        CORE::die @_,$y,"\n";
    }
}

my $method = rand(3);
die "I died\n" if $method > 2;
die "I died too" if $method > 1;
die;
```

Reports either

```
I died
I died too
<nothing - maybe not the right thing to do>
```

How to use the `CORE::GLOBAL::...` package is documented in [`perlsub`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?perlsub).

Comment: Works for `die`, but not for `croak` messages.

Answer (score 0):

I believe standard `die` output always contains `at` and `line` parts, so it should be enough to use:

```
s/\s+at\s(?!.*\bat\b).*\sline\s\d+\.$//;
```

Comment: That can match more then the OP's.

Comment: `die("There was a problem at the signup step\n");`

Comment: @ikegami - I believe OP wants to modify standard die outputs. Otherwise you can always find some example that would not work with any solution...